# How do I compare two nested data structures for unittesting?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, nested, data-comparison

For those who know perl, I'm looking for something similar to [`Test::Deep::is_deeply()`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Test-Deep-0.110/lib/Test/Deep.pm) in Python.

In [Python's unittest](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/unittest.html) I can conveniently compare nested data structures already, if I expect them to be equal:

```
self.assertEqual(os.walk('some_path'),
                 my.walk('some_path'),
                 "compare os.walk with my own implementation")
```

However, in the wanted test, the order of files in the respective sublist of the `os.walk` tuple shall be of no concern.

If it was just this one test it would be ok to code an easy solution. But I envision several tests on differently structured nested data. And I am hoping for a general solution.

I checked Python's own [unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.3/library/unittest.html), looked at [pyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/), and at [nose and it's plugins](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/builtin.html). Active maintenance would also be an important aspect for usage.

The ultimate goal for me would be to have a set of descriptive types like `UnorderedIterable`, `SubsetOf`, `SupersetOf`, etc which can be called to describe a nested data structure, and then use that description to compare two actual sets of data.

In the os.walk example I'd like something like:

```
comparison = OrderedIterable(
               OrderedIterable(
                 str,
                 UnorderedIterable(),
                 UnorderedIterable()
               )
             )
```

The above describes the kind of data structure that `list(os.walk())` would return. For comparison of data `A` and data `B` in a unit test, the current path names would be cast into a `str()`, and the dir and file lists would be compared ignoring the order with:

```
self.assertDeep(A, B, comparison, msg)
```

Is there anything out there? Or is it such a trivial task that people write their own? I feel comfortable doing it, but I don't want to reinvent, and especially would not want to code the full orthogonal set of types, tests for those, etc. In short, I wouldn't publish it and thus the next one has to rewrite again...

Answer (score 5):

[Python Deep](http://code.google.com/p/python-deep/) seems to be a project to reimplement perl's Test::Deep. It is written by the author of Test::Deep himself. Last development happened in early 2016.

Update (2018/Aug): Latest release (2016/Feb) is located on [PyPi/Deep](https://pypi.org/project/deep)

I have done some [P3k porting work on github](https://github.com/cfi/python-deep)

Comment: Unfortunately both links are dead. Could you please update your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but the currently implemented workaround to solve the particular example listed in the question:

```
    os_walk = list(os.walk('some_path'))
    dt_walk = list(my.walk('some_path'))
    self.assertEqual(len(dt_walk), len(os_walk), "walk() same length")
    for ((osw, osw_dirs, osw_files), (dt, dt_dirs, dt_files)) in zip(os_walk, dt_walk):
        self.assertEqual(dt, osw, "walk() currentdir")
        self.assertSameElements(dt_dirs, osw_dirs, "walk() dirlist")
        self.assertSameElements(dt_files, osw_files, "walk() fileList")
```

As we can see from this example implementation that's quite a bit of code. As we can also see, Python's unittest *has* most of the ingredients required.